How can the kabbalistic significance of the 42 masaos (desert stops) be known to other Kabbalists in light of it having been unknown to Ramban?
Malbim writes (Bamidbar 33:5) that the Kabbalists say that the 42 stops of Bamidbar 33 correspond to the 42 letter name of HaShem (והמקובלים כתבו שמ״ב מסעות אלה היו מכוונים נגד שם של מ״ב.), see there at length.
Otoh, Ramban (ibid ibid:1), after citing Rashi and Rambam's reasons for spelling out these stops, writes as follows:

והנה מכתב המסעים מצות השם היא מן הטעמים הנזכרים או מזולתם ענין לא נתגלה לנו סודו
Thus the writing down [the stages of] the journeyings was a commandment of G-d, either for the reasons mentioned above or for some other reasons, [for] a purpose the secret of which has not been revealed to us.

Ramban was one of the foremost Kabbalists of his day if not the most eminent of them all.
Kabbalah connotes received knowledge that is passed down from generation to generation.
How is it possible that something that Ramban was unaware of should be known to other (and presumably later) Kabbalists (cf אפשר אם משה לא ידע אלעזר יודע)?
(Are there multiple schools of this esoteric oral tradition one of which bypassed Ramban? Are there "kabbalistic" chiddushim [innovative explanations] that don't require being passed down?)

The most obvious answers I can think of are that the teachings of Kabbalah were spread out, and not all chains had the whole lot, and secondly that there information received since the Ramban from maggids, ruach hakodesh etc. and there were parts that were "underground" at the time of the Ramban, such as the Zohar that were rediscovered later. May I recommend learning the introduction to the Beis Yosef in שער האמונה ויסוד החסידות for a synopsis of the history of Kabbalah's transmission

The vast majority of kabbalistic ideas have no record in earlier sources. Not sure why this one is particularly notable.

@DoubleAA The vast majority don't have a Kabbalist of Ramban's stature explicitly declaring ignorance.

@RabbiKaii Thanks. I kind of alluded to your first suggestion. Regarding the zohar, do you mean that there was a complete oral gap? Regarding magidim etc, do you mean that anyone (on the right level) can have a personal "kabbalistic" revelation that was previously unknown (or forgotten)?

@Nahum yes there were gaps (complete?) and yes there have been certain figures like the Arizal and Besht who definitely gained Kabbalisitic knowledge from Ruach Hakodesh and communion with angels, and this is widely accepted as fact in many (probably most) Chareidi circles. The sefer I mentioned will go through this in much more detail

@Nahum so what? You think someone willing to accept all those other things were known but not mentioned is going to be bothered by the Ramban not spilling his hand on this one?

Kabbalah foundational principles were passed down, but there is always room for Chiddush within the guidelines. And the Arizal definitely revealed many new things.

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/134338/759
